# Creating database structure by using .NET DataSets

Tags: c#, .net, database, dataset

What is the easiest way to apply to database changes to the structure (not the data) made to DataSet? Do I need stuff like DataAdaptors? Is it possible to use in this way the DataSet that I configured via Visual Studio wizards? How to access such a DataSet?

Comment: what are the database changes that you'd like to apply?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could combine [DataSet.GetXmlSchema()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.getxmlschema.aspx) with an [XLST](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xslcompiledtransform.aspx) to generate the schema DDL. Another way would be to write a small program to parse each DataTable, it's DataColumns and DataRelations based on the available meta data (DataColumn.DataType, ColumnName, MaxLength, AllowNull, etc.) to build the DDL.

However, both approaches would only be good for new schemas, if you wanted to generate DDL for schema changes, then to be honest you'd probably save a lot of time by using an [existing product](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Compare/features.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, there's no built-in way to do this.

A `DataAdapter` adapts between a `DataSet` and the DML (Data Manipulation Language) of some database provider. There's no correspondence between a `DataSet` and the DDL (Data *Definition* Language) of a provider.

The one time I had to do this sort of thing, I wound up interpreting the DataSet myself. I had a program that accepted a bunch of "relational-like" metadata from a server, used it to construct a `DataSet`, then interpreted the `DataSet` to create the DDL. It then executed the DDL to create the database, filled the `DataSet` from the service, then finally used a `DataAdapter` to write the `DataSet` to the database.

It wasn't hard, just a bit time-consuming. I started by scripting out the initial database structure, then creating a `DataSet` that matched the structure. I then figured out which parts of the `DataSet` came from which parts of the DDL. I then learned how to go from the `DataSet` back to DDL. When the output from the `DataSet` matched the original DDL (more or less), then I considered myself done.